# regex for removing entity names

Tags: python, regex

Given tweets like the following:

```
Brick Brewing Co Limited (BRB) Downgraded by Cormark to Market Perform

Brinker International Inc (EAT) Upgraded by Zacks Investment Research to Hold
```

How do I write a regex that removes both `"by Cormark"` and `"by Zacks Investment Research"`

I tried this:

```
"by ([A-Za-z ]+\w to)"
```

using python but it requires the word "to". I would like the regex to stop before capturing the word "to".

It would also be interesting if someone could show me how to write a regex that captures camel-case examples, like `"Zacks Investment Research"`.

Comment: You mean to remove every string that starts with "by" and ends before "to" ?

Comment: There are many such strings, yes.

Comment: You can use non-capturing groups to ignore "by" and "to". Check this: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups.

Comment: @nikihub: A non-capturing group does not *ignore* anything, it just does not store the submatch in the buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [positive look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in order to exclude the word `to`:

```
>>> s1 = "Brick Brewing Co Limited (BRB) Downgraded by Cormark to Market Perform"
>>> 
>>> s2 = "Brinker International Inc (EAT) Upgraded by Zacks Investment Research to Hold"
>>> 
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'by[\w\s]+(?=to)','',s1)
'Brick Brewing Co Limited (BRB) Downgraded to Market Perform'
>>> re.sub(r'by[\w\s]+(?=to)','',s2)
'Brinker International Inc (EAT) Upgraded to Hold'
>>>
```

Note that the regex `[\w\s]+` will match any combination of word characters and white spaces. If you just want to match the alphabetical characters and white space you can use `[a-z\s]` with `re.I` flag (*Ignore case*).

Comment: If you plan to use this solution, do not forget the word boundaries around `to`: `(?=\bto\b)`.

Comment: @stribizhev I think there is no need to boundaries because the look-ahead doesn't match a `to` which is followed or precede by extra word characters.

Answer (score 2):

To remove all capitalized words after `by`, you can use

```
by [A-Z][a-z]*(?: +[A-Z][a-z]*)*
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vJ9mE9/1)

*Explanation*:

- `by`  - literal sequence of 3 characters `b`, `y` and a space
- `[A-Z][a-z]*` - a capitalized word (one uppercase followed by zero or more lowercase letters)
- `(?: +[A-Z][a-z]*)*` - zero or more sequences of...

  - `+[A-Z][a-z]*` - 1 or more spaces followed by an uppercase letter followed by zero or more lowercase letters.

A regular space may be replaced with `\s` in the pattern to match any whitespace. Also, to match CaMeL words, you can replace all `[a-z]` with `[a-zA-Z]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it with `str` method `index` then just slice and add up:

```
>>> def remove_name(s):
        b = s.index(' by ')
        t = s.index(' to ')
        s = s[:b]+s[t:]
        return s
>>> 
>>> s = 'Brick Brewing Co Limited (BRB) Downgraded by Cormark to Market Perform'
>>> remove_name(s)
'Brick Brewing Co Limited (BRB) Downgraded to Market Perform'
>>> 
>>> s = "Brinker International Inc (EAT) Upgraded by Zacks Investment Research to Hold"
>>> remove_name(s)
'Brinker International Inc (EAT) Upgraded to Hold'
```